# Using multiple includes of the same page in the same view

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

The environment is JSF 2, GlassFish, PrimeFaces.

I am working on an application for editing the data in a very complex model.

All classes in the model have relations to other classes, which in turn have relations to other classes, and so on. In many cases, for a given class, the "cluster" of relations (the whole expanded tree for the class) contains the same class at many places in the tree.

For example :

- Class A has relations to class B, C and D.
- Class B has no relations.
- Class C has relations to class B.
- Class D has relations to class E.
- Class E has relations to class B.

Now that I have summarized the context, here's what troubles me.

A design decision has been made to put *all* the data of a given instance of a class in the same page. The current architecture for doing this is the following for a given "root" class :

The "root" class is displayed in a PrimeFaces TabView. The tabs are :

- "Main" : contains the simple attributes (String, Integer, ...) of the class.
- There is one tab for each relation.
- In each tab, there is an include pointing to the appropriate XHTML file.

If the relation points to a single class, the XHTML file pointed to is similar to the "root" form described here. The adequate object is passed as a parameter to the XHTML file in the include directive. There are at most 3 nested TabViews.

If the relation points to a list, the XHTML file pointed to displays a list, with "add", "edit" and "delete" buttons. The adequate list is passed as a parameter to the XHTML file in the include directive.

There are additional complexities concerning lists, but I won't go there for the moment. Just with the single elements, we can see that there is a problem.

At first, I used the same parameter name for all XHTML files to be included. This does not work, because the parameter is "global" to the view. It seems to work for the initial display, but as soon as there is an update in one tab, I get an javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException because the form points to another object.

To mitigate the problem, I changed the parameter name to be unique for each class. Before, all parameters were called "element". After the modification, the parameter for class A is called "aElement", for class B it's "bElement", etc.

This works if all classes in a cluster are different. If a collision occurs, we are back to the same problem as before : in two different inclusions, we use the same parameter names, with different values.

I have thought about a very convoluted way to do it, but it uses Javascript :

- I pass an additional parameter to the XHTML forms, which is a unique identifier for the passed object.
- I get the identifier in the XHTML form, and put it in a hidden field, which is separated from the rest of the form.
- I make sure that the hidden field is never updated, read its value when the form gets focus, and retrieve the right object by an AJAX request using the value.

So my question is : is there a "pure" Java/JSF way to handle this ?

TL;DR : Thanks for reading !

Comment: "I used the same parameter name for all XHTML files to be included" - I understand that parameter is about the url to include? "I get an javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException because the form points to another object" - How are you updating the form? Are you doing `update="@form"`?

Answer (score 0):

For very complex natures CDI has a lot more to offer then plain JSF2. You could use producers and during runtime you can evaluate and modify objects freely.

You can keep track on what's already been produced and adapt the naming accordingly. For example save every occupied name in a map. Good luck.